# facebook sdk android, how to get user phone number?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

I want to know the user's phone number, but I can't find any mention in this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).

Is there any way to obtain the user's phone number?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/01/14/platform-updates--new-user-object-fields--edge-remove-event-and-more/

> Update: The user_address and user_mobile_phone permissions have been
>   removed. Please see this post for more info.

The post: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447/

> We’ll be working to launch these updates as soon as possible, and will
>   be temporarily disabling this feature until those changes are ready.
>   We look forward to re-enabling this improved feature in the next few
>   weeks.

This post is from 2011, next few weeks at Facebook are quite long..

We can conclude there is no way to get this information.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to get the phone number of a Facebook user via the Graph API. Even not if the user set it to public.

Have a look at the docs at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/#fields

Comment: Then how uber get it?